# Importing @AutoConfiguration class while using @ConditionalOnMissingBean in it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

I have ConfigA in one module and ConfigB in other module and they look like following snippet.

```
    @Configuration
    @Import({ConfigB.class})
public class ConfigA {
    @Bean
    Foo foo1(){}
}

@AutoConfiguration
public class ConfigB {
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "foo1")
    Foo foo2(){}
}
```

Because I am importing ConfigB to ConfigA, ConfigB is always created first so for that reason both Foo Beans will be created.
I am importing ConfigB to ConfigA because I want some other Beans to be imported.

So is there any way to keep the @Import but to instantiate only Foo bean from ConfigA without overriding beans?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it with using @ImportAutoConfiguration instead of @Import. Then first ConfigA gets instantiated and then ConfigB.